# Integrate Python validation script with HTML

Tags: python, html, xml

I am planning to build a simple web page that has an upload file option, submit button and a table to display the results.

- The file i would be uploading is an XML file.
- Upon submit, a python script should validate the XML file and display the discrepancies in the HTML page.

What is the best way to proceed with the front end and python integration? I have already validated the XML using python scripts but i am unable to find out a way to integrate it with HTML, upload & submit buttons.

Kindly help or let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a web framework to do this. Some good options for python are [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). HTML is meant to run on the client's browser, where Python (in this situation) is meant to run off of a server. Django, Flask, and others make this quick and easy to do.